# executing code (selector) while animating CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0;
[self.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation1"];
```

I would like to execute code when the degree is M_PI, in other words I have two buttons on the UIView and I want to change the labels of them while rotating the UIView and I don't want the user to feel the the buttons are changing in front of him so , best way is to execute the label changing while the UIView is rotating to half of the way.

Help me

Comment: I found a solution ,[self performSelector:@selector(switchLabels) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25]; and I put afterDelay the time when the degree is 90, if I set the animation duration 1 second then i put 0.25

Answer (score 0):

Split your `rotationAnimation` in two steps, each of `M_PI` radians rotation.
When the first animation is done (i.e., from the [animation's delegate `animationDidStop:finished:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation) function) start the second while also changing the label.

Or you could simply start the second animation after 0.5 sec.

Comment: its not good because when rotation finished the first state is returned.